# PHP textbox prevent special characters

Tags: php, textbox

Here is my code:

```
<tr class="top">
                <th><label for="userName"><?php echo NICKNAME; ?></label></th>
                <td>
                    <input id="userName" class="text" name="name" maxlength="15"        type="text" value="<?php echo $form->getValue('name'); ?>">
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $form->getError('name'); ?></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

I want to prevent special characters (like ^ < > ! ' + % &) and other characters (ç i ğ ü ö)

Full Php File: http://pastebin.com/RBQ2TF6S

I need code for this and please tell me it simply..

Thank you.

EDIT: My lang file:

```
define("USRNM_EMPTY","(Kullanıcı adı boş)");
define("USRNM_TAKEN","(İsim zaten kullanımda.)");
define("USRNM_SHORT","(min. ".USRNM_MIN_LENGTH." figures)");
define("USRNM_CHAR","(Geçersiz Karakterler)");
```

EDIT2: Or we can prevent register with db_mysql.php

```
function register($username, $password, $email, $tribe, $act) {
    $time = time();
    $timep = (time() + PROTECTION);
    $q = "INSERT INTO " . TB_PREFIX . "users (username,password,access,email,timestamp,tribe,act,protect,lastupdate,regtime) VALUES ('$username', '$password', " . USER . ", '$email', $time, $tribe, '$act', $timep, $time, $time)";
    if(mysql_query($q, $this->connection)) {
        return mysql_insert_id($this->connection);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you look in PHP manual? or Google it before posting?

Comment: If i found i dont write here..

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function register($username, $password, $email, $tribe, $act) {
    $time = time();
    $timep = (time() + PROTECTION);
    if (ctype_alnum($username)) {
      $q = "INSERT INTO " . TB_PREFIX . "users (username,password,access,email,timestamp,tribe,act,protect,lastupdate,regtime) VALUES ('$username', '$password', " . USER . ", '$email', $time, $tribe, '$act', $timep, $time, $time)";
      if(mysql_query($q, $this->connection)) {
          return mysql_insert_id($this->connection);
      } else {
          return false;
      }
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey my friend, where must i paste it?

Comment: Its nice, but i want dont register him.. I want give error to him. Edit: If he use special characters..

Comment: Ahh well in that case you can check if he is using special characters using if(ctype_alnum($username)) { /* give some error */ }

Comment: I have updated the code again, here the register function will only register the user if there are no special characters, otherwise it will not register and the function will return false so you can give a message explaining

Comment: Yes now it working nice. Now how can i give error message and where must i write? EDIT: define("USRNM_CHAR","(Geçersiz Karakterler)"); I have it in my lang file..

Comment: Where do you call the function register()? what you can do is put that in an if statement and give an error if it is false if(!register($username $password, etc)){ echo USERNM_CHAR; }